# remove adsense ads on subscription in website

Tags: adsense, adsense-api, google-ads-script

i want to know can i show ads for free users and remove ads if they purchase subscription in my website. (i have website).
and i want to done this in php if conditions like

```
if(subscription==true){
    // nothing here}
else{
    //  google adsense code here
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=############"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
}
```

i want to done like this.
can this voilance any google guidelines??
can if i done this my adsense got disapprove or rejected by chance??

Answer (score 0):

You can create another one web page or view thats not include section for google adsense code to generate the ads. But firstly you need to check your user subcription status then redirect it to the view not included ads when it was subscription users true